# Is there an official roadmap for the Tezos development?

Tags: untagged

I know that Tezos is a decentralized blockchain project and that everybody who wants to contribute can do so by pushing their code to the GitLab repo.

But there is at least one large development team in Paris. They must have some sort of plan on what they want to develop in the coming months/year. Is there a written roadmap in form of the following?

- Q1: Mempool improvements
- Q2: Stability- and performance improvements
- Q3: zk-SNARKs

I am asking because I like the dedicated roadmap website Cardano has.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: the title suggests that you are asking for a roadmap of the entire Tezos ecosystem (which there is not), but in your question you seem to restrict to a roadmap of a specific development team (presumably Nomadic Labs). Can you please clarify what it is exactly you are asking about because the answer will differ in each case. Thanks!

Comment: Tezos in general, yes. Or all of the major development teams / single codes. Just to get an idea where things are heading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tezos will never have anything "official". That's simply not possible for Decentralized Blockchain Projects. The moment something is "official", means somebody is in charge of it. That's not the case at Tezos.

Every Project, Code-Development has a Roadmap for sure. But not Tezos.

Comment: I kind of disagree, even though there is no official tezos roadmap, there *should* presumably be one at Nomadic Labs which i think is what the OP was referring to.

Comment: It could also be a community effort to gather several roadmaps by subject in a 'who does what' fashion for the community.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is (or should be) an "offical" one. The individual development teams have roadmaps probably, but they would have to propose any changes as amendments and they would need to pass a vote to be implemented.

YaY @ governance